# Two parents for one product yii2

Tags: database, controller, yii2, parent

Right now I've got two tables `"Category"` and `"Product"`. 
I made `'category_id'` in `"Product"` to be equal `'id'` in `Category`, so now in my view it shows all products of that category. But now I need one product to be in several categories.

In controller I use the following data provider:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query = Product::find()->where(['category_id' => $cats->id]),
        'sort'=>array(
            'defaultOrder'=>['id' => SORT_ASC],
        ),
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 9,
        ],
    ]);
```

Any suggestions on how to realise this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I did not understand it wrong your data structure to the pricipio

from 1 to N

```
 Categories -> Products
```

and now you want it to be from `N to N`
a category with many products and a product with many categories.

So I would like you to create another table called `Product_Categy` where you keep the primary keys of the 2 tables there and you have to be able to make relations from `N to N`, you would have a final scheme like this

```
Categories (id, ...) -> 
Categria_Product (id, id_categoria, id_producto, ...) <- Product (id, ..)
```

Comment: That's right! But maybe it's possible to just add another category_id (for example '1,2') ? If not - only another table would save me...

Comment: yes, you can add rows to separate the consecutive identifications with commas, but it destroys the philosophy of the relational tables and in the future when you want to keep it or expand it will be more difficult

I recommend doing things right from the beginning, but do what makes you happier

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query = Product::find()->where(['id' => $product_id]),
    'sort'=>array(
        'defaultOrder'=>['id' => SORT_ASC],
    ),
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 9,
    ],
]);

OR

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query = Product::find()->where(['id' => $product_id])->groupBy(['cats->id']),
    'sort'=>array(
        'defaultOrder'=>['id' => SORT_ASC],
    ),
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 9,
    ],
]);
```

Comment: how does your answer justify the `many to many` relations between 2 tables `product` and `category`.

Comment: Simple, if you search based on cat_id you can get different products under single cat_id. But the requirement is to get one product from multiple cat_id, so I change the condition.